# What is this Venn-Diagram-looking symbol?

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, current-source, comparator, symbol

So I am looking at the datasheet for the LTC4416, and there is this Venn-diagram symbol after the op-amp, but I don't think it is supposed to be an inverter. It is also used for these currents, but what do they physically represent?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually, a constant current.

Comment: The double-ring symbol is a current source...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a current source, it limits the current. The IG sources are switched on and off by the control circuitry to pull IG1 high or low. They are shown as current sources because the current is limited to these values:

[image]